# FIrebase - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J

Tags: java, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging, wildfly, guava

i'm working on a feature using google firebase cloud messaging to send notifications. It's a eclipse JEE java project using maven and ear deployment. I'm getting troubles trying to fetch my acces token from my json file using GoogleCredentials.

Here my piece of code, pretty simple for now.

```
private String getAccessToken(String keyName) throws IOException, ServiceException {
        try {

            String keyPath = "" + System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir") + "/gfpconfiguration/" + keyName
                    + ".json";

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(keyPath);

            GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(file)
                    .createScoped(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"));

            googleCredentials.refreshIfExpired();
            return googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
    }
```

When i'm running this on my local server (wildfly), i'm getting this error :

```
16:24:56,777 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J

16:24:56,777 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3)   at com.google.api.client.http.ConsumingInputStream.close(ConsumingInputStream.java:40) ~[google-http-client-1.42.2.jar:1.42.2]

16:24:56,777 INFO  [stdout] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3)   at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
```

I'm thinking about a dependency probleme, but no idea how to solve it. The weird thing is when I run my unit test everything is fine, I can get a valid token from the json file.

I read lot's of topics about this and all lead to a guava dependancy problem (maybe not). Here i my dependency hierarchy.

[image]

If I isolate this piece of code in normal simple java project, everything is also fine. Hope that someone have an idea of what's happenning. I'm pretty stuck. Let me know if you need more information/context.

I tried lot's of thing, changed version of firebase, guava, exclude guava from firebase dependancy, managed dependency... Also tried with this

```
byte[] tempByte = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyPath));
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tempByte);
```

still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by adding the following `jarModule` under `build/plugins/configuration/module` in my ear pom file.

```
<jarModule>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
</jarModule>
```